# Knex primary key auto increment

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using knex to create a simple table in postgres database:

```
function up(knex, Promise) {
return knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('communities', (table) => {

    table.increments('id').primary().unsigned();

    table.string('name', 255).notNullable();
    table.string('slug', 100).notNullable();

    table.timestamp('createdAt').defaultTo( knex.fn.now() );
    table.timestamp('updatedAt');
});
```

};

```
function down(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(tableName);
};

module.exports = {
    tableName,
    up,
    down
}
```

My problem is that `table.increments('id').primary()` creates a primary key that for default value has `nextval('communities_id_seq'::regclass)` and I can't do an insert without an id (even in raw sql).

Does anyone know how to make the id increment by default?

Comment: You probably should use type `serial`, rather than `unsigned`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that the value for id was an empty string and not undefined or null, so that was braking the constraint for integer as data type.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

In js:
`table.increments()`

Output sql:
`id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key`

[check this out for more information](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-increments)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but I was having this issue with the same use case. However my solution was I didnt have all the correct permissions granted to my sequences, only my tables when i ceated the DB.

So something along the lines of `"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC"`